# Retornar classes do arquivo CSS usando Regex e PHP

Tags: php, css, array, regex

Tenho o Seguinte CSS:

```
.icon-a{
    background:black;
    color:white;
}    
.icon-b{
    backgroundwhite;
    color:black;
}    
.icon-c{
    background:blue;
    color:yellow;
}
```

Queria um script em PHP que pudesse ler o arquivo CSS e retornasse somente as classes do seletor em um array:
Ex:

```
Array(
    0 => "icon-a",
    1 => "icon-b",
    2 => "icon-c"
 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode usar essa expressão regular, `\.[\w-]+` um ponto seguindo de letra/número[a-zA-Z0-9] um traço combinando mais de uma vez, o modificar `m` faz a combinação funcionar em multilas linhas.

```
<?php

$css  ='.icon-a{
    background:black;
    color:white;
}    
.icon-b{
    backgroundwhite;
    color:black;
}    
.icon-c{
    background:blue;
    color:yellow;
}';


preg_match_all('#\.[\w-]+#m', $css, $m);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($m);
```